# High Throughput on BGP Multihomed Network

Tags: bgp, qos, performance

I've One site connected to my server location via BGP over MPLS and at my server location 2 edge routers cater these WAN links, and are further connected to Servers via switches.

[image]

Now, Is it possible to fully utilize the link capacity of the both the links and simultaneously ensure that if there are drops or latency on one link, router automatically utilizes more of the other ??

After googling much, have only found Subnet division for utilizing both the links but didn't got anything how to tackle latency/drops.

Please guide.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, and what criteria you will use.  Network performance can vary rapidly, and you don't want to overreact to a momentary problem.

You don't mention the types of routers you have, but Cisco has a feature called Optimized Edge Routing that will do what you want.  I'm sure juniper and other major manufacturers have similar functions.

Comment: Im using Cisco Routers; for AS 500 C841M/C1921 and for Edge Routers ISR4331.

Comment: My ultimate aim to ensure redundancy (by having multiple links) and reliability (by fully utilizing the capacity of both the links) of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement MPLS-TE:
1.- create 2 TE tunnels, each going through a different edge router
2.- make the server and the router in asn500 to use them for their MP-BGP session.
3.- enable load-balancing and fast-reroute between the tunnels
4.- several features of the TE tunnels will allow you to handle the BW requirements

Answer (score 0):

Load-balancing based on latancy/drop/jitter metrics can be achieved on Cisco ISR-G2 or more recent edge routers using PfRv3.
This was part of Cisco's Intelligent WAN solution that was being pushed before Cisco SD-WAN.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/performance-routing-pfr/200182-Configure-Load-balancing-on-PFRv3.html

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/pfrv3/configuration/xe-3s/pfrv3-xe-3s-book/pfrv3.html